# Validation Regex for HTML

Tags: html, css, regex, razor

Hey guys I need to use some validation on my HTML page, I am looking to do the following:

Must begin with the letters PC or pc followed by 1 to 5 digits.

This is what I have:

```
Validation.Add("ProductCode", Validator.Required("Must begin with PC and contain 1-5 digits"), Validator.Regex(@"\[P p][C c]d{5}?"));
```

I also want a message to come up beside the textbox when it is entered incorrectly, I thought this was done by the Validation.Required, however it does not seem to be working.

Thanks

Comment: try this regular expression
`((p|P)(c|C)\d{5}).* `
Let me know if you want it with Data Annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the syntax needed for Razor but something like this should work:

`/^pc\d{1,5}$/ig` (JS equivalent)

---

### Edit

From what I've been able to find you can add `(?i)` to the beginning of an expression (or at the location) to make it case insensitive from that point on with Razor:

`^(?i)pc\d{1,5}$` or `^(?i:pc)\d{1,5}$`

**Note:** due to the use of `^` and `$` this regex will only match *PC* and 1 to 5 digits. If you had *PC* and 6 digits or *PC* and 5 digits and some other character(s) it would not match.

Anyone more familiar with Razor/C# regex feel free to chime in.

Comment: Just edited your answer to this instead, works a char, thank you everyone :)
^(?i)pc\d{1,5}$

Answer (score 0):

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(5)]
[MinLength(1)]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage =" Must begin with PC and contain 1-5 digits")]
public string ProductCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: I havent seen it be done this way before, the above example I have is the way I have always used the validation and regex

Comment: @J.Gold, using attributes is much cleaner. I wouldn't shy away from it just because that's how you've 'always used the validation and regex'.